# Convert QStackedLayout to QHBoxLayout dynamically

Tags: qt, layout

I would like to change my widget layout from `QStackedLayout` to `QHBoxLayout` to `QVBoxLayout` dynamically by clicking on push buttons. I am able to switch from `QVBoxLayout` to `QHBoxLayout` and vice versa, but my approach does not work for `QStackedLayout`. I've exhausted all options I can think of. A sample code is attached. Does anyone know how I can achieve my objective?

```
#ifndef WIDGET_H
#define WIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QStackedLayout>
#include <QGridLayout>
#include <QLabel>

class Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Widget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Widget();
    QPushButton *button1_;
    QPushButton *button2_;
    QPushButton *button3_;

    QHBoxLayout *hLayout_;
    QVBoxLayout *vLayout_;
    QStackedLayout *sLayout_;
    QVBoxLayout *gLayout_;

public slots:
    void layoutHorizontal();
    void layoutVertical();
    void layoutStacked();

private:
    bool isStackedLayout_;
    QLabel *bar_;
};

#endif // WIDGET_H


#include "widget.h"
#include <QtAlgorithms>
#include <QDebug>

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent){

    bar_ = new QLabel(tr("TEST!"));

    button1_ = new QPushButton(tr("to Horizontal Layout"),(bar_));
    button2_ = new QPushButton(tr("to Vertical Layout"),(bar_));
    button3_ = new QPushButton(tr("to Stacked Layout"),(bar_));

    button1_->setStyleSheet("background: rgba(255,255,0,255);");
    button2_->setStyleSheet("background: rgba(255,0,255,255);");
    button3_->setStyleSheet("background: rgba(0,255,255,255);");

    connect(button1_,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(layoutHorizontal()));
    connect(button2_,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(layoutVertical()));
    connect(button3_,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(layoutStacked()));


    gLayout_ = new QVBoxLayout;
    setLayout(gLayout_);

    hLayout_ = new QHBoxLayout(bar_);
    hLayout_->setObjectName(tr("currentLayout"));
    gLayout_->addWidget(bar_);

    hLayout_->addWidget(button1_);
    hLayout_->addWidget(button2_);
    hLayout_->addWidget(button3_);

    isStackedLayout_ = false;

    resize(480,200);

}

Widget::~Widget() { }

void Widget::layoutHorizontal(){
    QLayout *layout = bar_->findChild<QLayout *>(tr("currentLayout"));
    layout->removeWidget(button1_);
    layout->removeWidget(button2_);
    layout->removeWidget(button3_);

    delete layout;

    QHBoxLayout *hLayout_ = new QHBoxLayout(bar_);
    hLayout_->setObjectName(tr("currentLayout"));
    hLayout_->addWidget(button1_);
    hLayout_->addWidget(button2_);
    hLayout_->addWidget(button3_);

    isStackedLayout_ = false;

}

void Widget::layoutVertical(){
    QLayout *layout = bar_->findChild<QLayout *>(tr("currentLayout"));
    layout->removeWidget(button1_);
    layout->removeWidget(button2_);
    layout->removeWidget(button3_);
    delete layout;

    QVBoxLayout *vLayout_ = new QVBoxLayout(bar_);
    vLayout_->setObjectName(tr("currentLayout"));

    vLayout_->addWidget(button1_);
    vLayout_->addWidget(button2_);
    vLayout_->addWidget(button3_);

    isStackedLayout_ = false;
}

void Widget::layoutStacked(){
    QLayout *layout = bar_->findChild<QLayout *>(tr("currentLayout"));
    layout->removeWidget(button1_);
    layout->removeWidget(button2_);
    layout->removeWidget(button3_);
    delete layout;

    QStackedLayout *sLayout_ = new QStackedLayout(bar_);
    sLayout_->setObjectName(tr("currentLayout"));

    sLayout_->addWidget(button1_);
    sLayout_->addWidget(button2_);
    sLayout_->addWidget(button3_);

    isStackedLayout_ = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The visibility property on your buttons gets set to "invisible" after pulling widgets out of the `QStackedLayout` (likely because the `QStackedLayout` relies on this property to emulate stacking).  As such, I was able to get your code to work by adding the following:

```
void Widget::layoutHorizontal() {

   ...

   button1_->setVisible(true);
   button2_->setVisible(true);
   button3_->setVisible(true);

   isStackedLayout_ = false;
}
```

It's also worth noting that removing the widgets from the layout prior to deleting it is not necessary.  The layout doesn't take ownership of the widgets in it.  As such you can delete the following:

```
layout->removeWidget(button1_);
layout->removeWidget(button2_);
layout->removeWidget(button3_);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create another widget with only widgets and one layout inside. Then use **setLayout** for your widget. Sorry for my bad C++ knowledge :)

```
class ChangeableWidget: public QWidget {

    private QVBoxLayout vbox;
    private QHBoxLayout hbox;
    private QStackedLayout stacked;

    private QPushButton button1;
    private QPushButton button2;

    ChangeableWidget() 
    {
        button1 = new QPushButton("1");
        button2 = new QPushButton("2");

        vbox = new QVBoxLayout();
        vbox.addWidget(button1);
        vbox.addWidget(button2);

        hbox = new QHBoxLayout();
        hbox.addWidget(button1);
        hbox.addWidget(button2);        

        stacked = new QStackedLayout();
        stacked.addWidget(button1);
        stacked.addWidget(button2);

        setLayout(vbox);
    }

    void ChangeableWidget::layoutVertical()
    {
        setLayout(vbox);
    }

    void ChangeableWidget::layoutHorizontal()
    {
        setLayout(hbox);
    }    
}
```